# Give an example of finitely generated group with a non-finitely generated subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is there any finitely generated group with a non-finitely generated subgroup?  ($G$ is a finitely generated group if $\exists H\subset G$ ,$\langle H\rangle=G$ such that $H$ is intersection of all subgroup of $G$ that these $H$ is subset of these subgroups.) Thanks in advance

Comment: @YACP:  Thanks for finding the duplicate question.  I was sure there would be one but didn't find it in the quick search I tried.  As for your reasons for voting down, I think only the last is at all valid, and even then it's better to first leave a comment asking to show effort.  It's unfair to vote down for bad but comprehensible English, and I don't see what you mean by 'bad mathematical notions'.

Comment: @YACP:  Yes, it does, it's clear that it means 'finitely generated'.  By the way, did you flag this as a duplicate?